# Laravel 5 Datatable Error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was trying to configure chumper Datatables in Laravel 5 but I get an Error related to view

```
View [views.template] not found. (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel-
master\resources\views\songs\index.blade.php)
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the cause?

Chumper datatable is not found in laravel 5 but the following link says that it is configurable in laravel 5

http://jayeshmagare.blogspot.in/2015/02/using-chumper-datatable-in-laravel-5.html

Really, in need of this datatable.

Here, are my Controller,Route and View ->

Controller

```
public function getDatatable()
{
     return Datatable::collection(Songs::all(array('id','title')))
     ->showColumns('id', 'title')
     ->searchColumns('title')
     ->orderColumns('id','title')
     ->make();
}
```

Route

```
$router->resource('songs','SongsController');
get('api/songs',['as'=>'api.songs','uses'=>'SongsController@getDatatable']);
```

View

```
 <div class="box-body table-responsive">
 {!! Datatable::table()
->addColumn('ID','Date')       
->setUrl(route('api.songs'))       
->noScript()
->render()
->script(); !!}
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't be using facades like that within the view. The controller should be passing the result set in. Separate your logic.

Comment: This error is related to the view. Chumper appears (I have never used it) to be unable to find the template view in its package. It is looking in your app's view folder not the package view folder (Github repo shows this to be at chumper/datatable/src/views). Did you use composer to install Chumper?

Comment: I guess no one has the answer

Answer (score 1):

In view file replace below code. It will work

```
{!! Datatable::table()
    ->addColumn('ID','Date')      
    ->setUrl(route('api.songs'))  
    ->render() !!}
```